# Can I set permission on who can use a certain page layout?

Tags: 2010, permissions, page-layout

On our SharePoint site, we're currently using three types of custom page layouts:

> - SingleColumn
> - TwoColumn
> - NoNavigation

Is it possible to restrict usage of say `NoNavigation` to only Site Collection admins?
Only Site Collection admins should be the only one to be able to create pages of this type, or change the page layout of a page to this type. Regular users/owners can still edit the content of the page, but are not able to change the page layout to `NoNavigation`.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You can set permissions on who can see it in the masterpage gallery, but not in the available page layout templates list.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought too. Just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's impossible.

You can set permissions directly for your page layout within SharePoint Designer, but it's no a solution for you.
(SharePoint Designer -> Page Layouts -> Permissions -> Stop Inheriting)